# JSF: How to check if a image is valid to display

Tags: java, image, jsf, richfaces

For my application I dynamically download images for results form a database. I use a4j:mediaOutput to display them. The problem is that some images returned are not valid to display (can't even display them on a PC). Is there a way I can detect such thing and display something like 'image unavailable' in it's place? I don't mean what happens if my image isn't downloaded or I can't connect to get it - this is easily done by checking if the byte array is null. The problem is that if I download an image but i.e. it is corrupted so can't be displayed. Does anyone have any advice?

Comment: I wonder how image aren't readable ? how they are stored in DB then

Comment: You may want to elaborate on what "not valid to display" means, and what should be done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to use javax.imageio to validate image format (ImageReader.getFormatName()) after downloading.

Comment: Thanks Lev - the ImageReader seems to be working :> I only wish the return string was like a mime type. So "image/jpeg" instead of "JPEG". This way I could easily compare them with the mime i receive from the server.